# What is the "McCaul-Thompson" bill that may be part of Trump's DACA deal?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, congress, immigration, illegal-immigration

Today House Minority Leader Nancy Pelosi and Senate Minority Leader Chuck Schumer issued a [joint statement](https://www.democraticleader.gov/newsroom/91417/) concerning the tentative agreement President Trump made with them last night:

> President Trump’s Tweets are not inconsistent with the agreement reached last night.  As we said last night, there was no final deal, but there was agreement on the following:
>
> We agreed that the President would support enshrining DACA protections into law, and encourage the House and Senate to act.
>
> What remains to be negotiated are the details of border security, with a mutual goal of finalizing all details as soon as possible.  While both sides agreed that the wall would not be any part of this agreement, the President made clear he intends to pursue it at a later time, and we made clear we would continue to oppose it.
>
> Both sides agreed that the White House and the Democratic leaders would work out a border security package.  Possible proposals were discussed including new technology, drones, air support, sensor equipment, rebuilding roads along the border **and the bipartisan McCaul-Thompson bill**.

My question is, what is the "McCaul-Thompson bill" being referred to?  It must have something to do with border security.

Answer (score 3):

It's the proposed 2013 bill concerning border security from Rep. Michael McCaul, R-Texas, amended by proposals from Rep. Bennie Thompson, D-Miss.

Unless I'm mistaken this is the bill (H.R.1417, "Border Security Results Act of 2013"):

https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-bill/1417

> From the Congressional Record, Volume 159 (2013)
>
> H.R. 1417--A bill to require the Secretary of Homeland Security to develop a  omprehensive strategy to gain and maintain operational control of the international borders of the United States, and for other purposes; to the Committee on Homeland Security.
>
> By Mr. McCAUL (for himself, Mrs. Miller of Michigan, Ms. Jackson Lee,  and Mr. Thompson of Mississippi), H1856 [9AP]
>
> Cosponsors added, H1959 [11AP], H1994 [12AP], H2027 [15AP], H2161   [18AP], H2300 [24AP], H2396 [26AP], H2405 [3MY], H2485 [7MY], H2604 [14MY]
>
> Reported with amendment (H. Rept. 113-87), H2802 [20MY]

---

One source discussing the bill seems to be [this](https://homeland.house.gov/press/houston-chronicle-rep-michael-mccaul-wins-committee-approval-tough-border-security/):

> House Republicans led by Texas Rep. Michael McCaul are making gains in their effort to require the Obama administration to develop a yardstick for measuring federal law enforcement agencies’ “operational control” of the U.S. border before spending more money on border security.
>
> Before McCaul’s legislation cleared the panel, Rep. Bennie Thompson, D-Miss., led an effort by House Democrats to pencil in $3 billion in projected spending to help federal law enforcement agencies meet the higher standard for operational control.

Comment: As far as I can tell from reporting, Mccaul lost interest in that bill and introduced a new one later that year.